# Calling SLNode<E> find() method

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am working on an assignment for school where a SinglyLinkedList class is provided and we are supposed to create a program that makes calls to this class to add, delete, find, and display items in a list. I have implemented the add, delete and display methods just fine, but I can't figure out how to call the find method. Any help would be great.

Here is the method from the SinglyLinked Class which I need to implement:

```
private SLNode<E> find( E target ) {
SLNode<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();

while ( cursor != tail ) {
  if ( cursor.getElement().equals( target ) ) {
    return cursor; // success
  }
  else {
    cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
  }
}

return null; // failure
```

}

Here is what I have...I've included the implementations of the other methods as well:

```
public static void addPet()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your pet's name and what type of \n    animal it is(i.e. \"Mickey, Mouse\"): \n");
    petType = keyboard.nextLine();
    pet.add(petType, 0);
    System.out.printf("%s was added to the list.\n\n", petType);        
}

public static void displayPets()
{       
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<pet.getLength(); i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("\n%d.\t%s",i+1, pet.getElementAt(i));
    }
    System.out.print("\n\n");
}

public static void deletePet()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    String a;
    for(i=0; i<pet.getLength(); i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("\t%d. %s\n",i+1, pet.getElementAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the number of the item to delete: \n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    j = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("%s was deleted from the list.\n\n", pet.getElementAt(j-1));
    pet.remove(j-1);
}

public static void findPet()
{
    String keyword;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
    keyword = keyboard.nextLine();
    //.find(keyword);
}
```

I'm sure I will kick myself because it's simpler than I'm making it, but I'm really just stuck.

Comment: @samack, he already posted what he got so far.

Comment: What is the type of the pet variable? `SinglyLinked` what?  `SinglyLinked<String>`?

Comment: Yes, String. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your list apparently contains pets, represented by some pet type (which looks like a `String`). So `find` expects a similar pet type you added in `addPet`. And returns an `SLNode` containing the found pet, if there is one. Since you haven't posted `SLNode`, I can't tell how to get the element contained in it, but calling `getElement()` on it looks like a safe bet :-) So you need to check the value returned by `find`, for `null`ness. If it's not `null`, you can e.g. get the element contained in it and print it.

I suppose this should be enough for you to write the code; if it's not clear, please comment.

Comment: SLNode was not provided to us.

Comment: @Brandon, OK, then I guess the point of the exercise is simply to check whether the item in question is present in the list or not. In other words, you should print a message like "Found!" if the value returned by `find` is not null, and "Not found!" if it is null.

Comment: I tried to call pet.getElement(keyword), but it just says: Pet.java:73: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getElement(java.lang.String)
location: class gray.adts.ch3.SinglyLinkedList<java.lang.String>
  pet.getElement(keyword);

Comment: I'm still not sure how to actually call the find method, even to return true or false. Any idea?

Comment: @Brandon, OK, I think I know why. The `find` method you showed above is `private`, hence it can't be called from outside `SinglyLinkedList`. Are you sure this is the method you need to use? Is there any other method in that class with a similar name but `public` qualifier?

Comment: There are two find methods and they are both private. The teacher for this class has no idea what he's doing and any attempt to ask him for clarification on the assignment is usually met with "Just figure it out". I have produced an answer a different way. I first printed the items in the list then I changed the keyboard and keyword to 'int' and prompted the user to enter the # of the element they want to find and called the 'getElementAt' method from the SinglyLinkedList class. Then, I printed "Found. Displaying: "+pet.getElementAt(keyword - 1).

Comment: I have no idea if this is what he wants, but it may be what I have to go with.